# Hover menu inside a menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand display-4">NintendoWorlds</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Games</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Latest</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Best Selling</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
@media all and (min-width:992px){
    .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu{display:none;}
    .navbar .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu{display:block;}
    .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu{margin-top:0;}
}
ul.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item{
    padding: 14px;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

I want to display a menu when I hover the mouse over "Our Pick". Can you guys show me how to do it?

Comment: Where is the submenu you want to show when you hover over `Our Pick`

Comment: I want to show it on the right of our pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a nested `ul` element inside your our pick `li` and show the sub `menu` for our pick on the `right` of our pick.

We can do this using [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class . The `submenu` will hide itself when you move the mouse from `Our Pick`

**Live Working Demo**

```css
@media all and (min-width:992px) {
  .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

ul.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item {
  padding: 14px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.our-pick {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sub-menu:hover .our-pick {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand display-4">NintendoWorlds</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Games</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Latest</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Best Selling</a></li>
          <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick</a>
            <ul class="our-pick">
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you put <ul class="our-pick"></ul> inside <li class="sub-menu"></li>? Is that matter if I put <ul></ul> outside of <li></li>? The code is great, thank you so much

Comment: @QuangnGUYEN You are welcome. and uou can put it outside as well. It will work that was as well. But just for better coding practice i prefer its good to have menu item with nested submenu inside it. so that its clear.

Comment: @QuangnGUYEN If you like to put it outside the our pick `li` then you can use `+` which is called `adjacaent sibling selector` in your CSS :hover. But its to have it inside for better practice. Same results but better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If the menu is directly placed after the link, as such:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Latest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Best Selling</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Our Pick</a>
        <ul class = "menu">
         // menu
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can use the `+` selector in CSS:

```
.dropdown-item:hover + .menu { display:block; }
```